# What tornadic wind speed would be required to destroy a reinforced masonry structure?

Tags: science-based, weather, infrastructure

Tornadoes are well-known to be one of the most destructive forces on the planet, packing the capacity to practically delete small towns from the map and lay waste to billions of dollars worth of buildings.  However, even with the highest winds recorded on this planet at an astounding 315mph, no tornado has ever been documented to flatten a high-rise or heavy institutional structure (such as a major hospital or government building); in fact, the Degrees of Damage used in the Enhanced Fujita scale for measuring damage to [high-rise](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5a/EF_DI19_%28HROB%29.jpg) and [instutitional](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/EF_DI20_%28IB%29.jpg) buildings top out at "significant structural deformation" and "significant damage to building envelope", respectively.

Given that a tornado capable of destroying such heavy construction would still be rated EF5, what sort of wind speeds would be required to inflict total devastation (not just facade and systems damage, but structural damage to the point of collapse, significant partial collapse, or gross instability that renders the building manifestly uninhabitable) upon a structure as soundly built as a skyscraper (especially an older, lightly-glazed building using a stone/masonry curtain wall facade) or heavy-frame institutional building, or some other sort of heavy/reinforced masonry building (such as a historical aboveground fort/castle) that isn't specifically designed to withstand a tornado for that matter?  We can assume that the tornado is already loaded with typical debris such as 2x4s, miscellaneous building debris, and vehicles/vehicle parts, if the debris already present at the time of the strike matters at all.

Comment: Just to set an expectation. North of my birth city lies an abandoned reinforced concrete structure that the county has tried to remove - with explosives - and failed. Today it's a monument to both creative and banal graffiti. Having said that, have you looked up the air pressure/speed used for sandblasting? That would be the lowest end of the scale, I should think.

Answer (score 3):

500km/hr wind on it's own would not destroy a well built reinforced building. But the wind can bring 3 things which can:

- Projectiles. [This paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S2352012420302101) describes the structural damage from a car hitting reinforced concrete pillars at 40km/hr. (The column gets a sheer fracture). Scaling this up to tornado speeds and a few lucky impacts with flying cars into structural members could condemn a building.
- Fire. Tornado's rupture gas and fuel lines. Those lines can feed fires, which weaken structural components. Or you can just directly melt it - concrete melts at about 1200 - 1700 degrees C (depends on composition), natural gas burns at 1900 degrees C.
- Water. A fast moving storm surge impacts much more force than the same speed of air. A tsunami-like effect can be created by strong winds.

Reinforced building survivability in extreme winds is more a combination of luck and surroundings that just wind speed.

But if you really want a number for wind destroying reinforced concrete:

[This table can convert wind speed to force](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.thermosolar.sk/wp-content/uploads/download/certifikaty/protokoly/TS300-TS250-TS500/Windspeed-to-Pressure-conversion-chart-23.9.11.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjy8PKj-9XrAhUFxjgGHW7cAe0QFjAIegQICxAB&usg=AOvVaw1w0G4_IBUaQbN0EhF5Suey). Your reinforced concrete is rated at 50-70mpa under compression. The wind force of 300km/hr is around 5kpa. So youd need winds... 10,000 times stronger.

Comment: Great answer with tables and references to help the OP and future users. Thanks!

Comment: At a certain point it’s more likely that the wind will undermine the foundations of the building by scouring the surrounding countryside to the bedrock...